# tfjs-node-gpu invalid ELF header on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, tensorflow

I'm trying to run [tensorflow/tfjs-examples/mnist-node](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/mnist-node) on Windows with GPU.

After cloning the repository and installing the dependencies, I can run the example with CPU. However, when I tried to install `@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu` and run the example, here's what I get:

```
Registration of backend tensorflow failed
Error: The specified module could not be found.    
\\?\C:\Users\noob\Desktop\tfjs-examples\mnist-node\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node-gpu\build\Release\tfjs_binding.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at bindings (C:\Users\noob\Desktop\tfjs-examples\mnist-node\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:81:44)
    at C:\Users\noob\Desktop\tfjs-examples\mnist-node\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node-gpu\dist\index.js:10:60
    at Environment.registerBackend (C:\Users\noob\Desktop\tfjs-examples\mnist-node\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\environment.js:188:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\noob\Desktop\tfjs-examples\mnist-node\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node-gpu\dist\index.js:9:9)
```

According to [tfjs-node](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-node), it seems like I've already fit the requirements. Here's my environments:

**Environment:**

- node v10.9.0
- nvcc 9.2 V9.2.148
- Windows 10 version 1803 build 17738.1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Problem solved. I have to install CUDA **v9.0** instead of v9.2. After uninstall and reinstall it works again.

Here's some tutorial if someone have similar problem.

1. First download *CUDA 9.0* and *cuDNN v7 for CUDA 9.0*, install CUDA 9.0.
2. Extract cuDNN files to your CUDA installation folder. (Default to `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0`)
3. Add `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin` and `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\lib\x64` to PATH.
4. run `node main` in tfjs-examples\mnist-node, it would work now.

At the first time, it may take about 2~5 minutes stuck at `Adding visible gpu devices: 0`, just wait for it. I'll work.

BTW, you cannot use GPU in WSL mode yet.